# Ruby program convention

Tags: ruby, format, convention

I am new to programming and need some advise on the layout/structure of a program. Can you advise if this is the correct way to structure a program in ruby?

This program moves files from an SD card to named folder and gives the option to name the files.

```
Dir.chdir '/home/moot/pickaxe/pics' #replace this with destination directory

$pic_names = Dir['/media/moot/**/*.{CR2,cr2,JPG,jpg}'] #replace this with sd card directory

def folder
 puts "Enter the folder name"
 while $folder_name = gets.chomp
 if File.exist?("#{$folder_name}")
   puts "This folder already exists, choose a unique name"
 else
   require 'fileutils'
   FileUtils::mkdir_p "/home/moot/pickaxe/pics/#{$folder_name}"
   break
   end 
  end
end

def files
  puts "Do you want to name the files? Answer y/n"
  while question = gets.chomp
    if question == "y"
      puts "What do you want to call them?"
      $file_name = gets.chomp
      print "Downloading #{$pic_names.length} Files: "
      pic_number = 1
      $pic_names.each do |name|
      print 'ˁ˚ᴥ˚ˀ  '
      new_name = if pic_number < 10
      "#{$file_name} 0#{pic_number} .CR2"
    else
      "#{$file_name} #{pic_number} .CR2"
    end
    require 'fileutils'
    include FileUtils
    cp(name, new_name)  
    pic_number = pic_number + 1
    end
    break
    elsif question == "n"
    print "Downloading #{$pic_names.length} Files: "
        $pic_names.each do |name|
        print 'ˁ˚ᴥ˚ˀ  '
    new_dir = "/home/moot/pickaxe/pics/#{$folder_name}"
    require 'fileutils'
    include FileUtils
    cp(name, new_dir)
    end
    break
    else 
      puts "Please answer y/n"
    end
  end
end    

folder
Dir.chdir "/home/moot/pickaxe/pics/#{$folder_name}"
files
puts "Move Complete."
```

Comment: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place for questions like these.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby conventions generally promote shorter methods, as this improves readability, testability, etc. (Though in the end it's up to you as programmer to decide what's best to accomplish the task at hand.)

One way you might achieve this is to think about your problem in English or other human language first, and break it down into its component parts.

In other words, what specific steps are involved to solve the problem?

Those steps will likely correspond to methods, and perhaps entities--embodied as Ruby classes or modules--that model your problem domain (in fancy programmer-speak).

Practice makes perfect, and coding is the best practice, but it also helps to read code created by others.